# Angular ngIf statement

Tags: angular, conditional-statements, angular-ng-if, ng-switch

This is a component that reuse in a form for registering item. here i have some types.
like for a phone number there are work, home, mobile types. value for 'data' are taken from service file. 
type.component.html

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="types">
    <select [ngModel]="selectedIndex" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.code">
        {{ type.code }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="data">
    <select [ngModel]="selectedIndex" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item.id">
        {{ item.name }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </ng-container>
```

type.component.ts

```
@Input()
  get data(): User[] {
    return this._data;
  }

@Input()
 get types(): Type[] {
   return this._types;
 }

 set types(value: Type[]) {
   this._types = value;
 }

 set data(value: User[]) {
   this._data = value;
   this.userservice.getUserList();
 }

 private _types: Type[] = [];
 private _data: User[] = [];
```

in form.component.html I reuse above `type.component.html` as `my-type`. when i use `<my-type [data]="userData"></my-type>` it should call second if condition. And `<my-type [types]="typeData"></my-type>` it should call first if condition.
 now both of conditions are called and display two components. when I use `*ngSwitch`  it doesn't work for `data`. 
 How can I solve this?

Comment: I think the problem is that your `*ngIf` condition always evaluates to `true`  because your default values are empty arrays.  try initializing `_types` and `_data` to `undefined`  instead of `[]` and see if it works.

Comment: You're question isn't very clear. In your component though, you are setting both `_types` and `_data` to empty arrays, so `*ngIf="data"` will never be false. Maybe try `*ngIf="data.length"` instead?

Comment: Your `@Input`s should be on your setters